# How to implement scheduling inside a running thread group?

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am testing a certain "functionality" that happens after log in.

The test case is 500 users exercising that functionality within 5 minutes.

I can add a synchronising timer after the log in, to ensure all 500 threads have logged in but then it will do all 500 "functionality" tasks at once, rather than 5 minutes, which will crash the app (it thinks there's a DDoS attack and shuts down).

Right now, I am handling this by giving some think time after login, to slow down login to a stable figure that I can predict and then start "functionality" at each thread's turn, as scheduled by: 
 the main scheduler 
 + the the log in response time 
 + the think time...

But that's a bit fuzzy.
Is there a way to "ramp up" tasks once already running?

Comment: You need to get more clarity in terms of throughput, if you know how much throughput you are looking at, use Throughput controller on top of the activity you want to complete.

Answer (score 0):

I can think in two options.

The first one is two use random times. You would use the range from `0` seconds to `300 - 1` that is `[0-300)` or using millis `[0-300000)`. Then sleep the thread basesd on this ramdon time.

This approach can be a little more realist, because for instance, in a specific second of the given interval you don't have any threads starting and in other particular second you have 2-3. This still should be well balanced in general, since you won't make all petitions at start.

The second one is to start the threads uniformly. During your configuration time (login and before firing the threads) you can use something like an [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), initializing it with `new AtomicInteger(0)` and calling `getAndIncrement()` to assign the possition of the thread, in the range `[0-500)` and then when you fire the threads sleep `300.0 * id / 500.0` milliseconds to execute the task/petition.

Answer (score 0):

By default JMeter executes requests as fast as it can, you can "throttle" the execution to desired throughput (request per minute) rate using [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer).

Example Test Plan would look like:

- Thread Group

  - Login

    - Synchronizing Timer
  - Functionality

    - Constant Throughput Timer

Constant Throughput Timer follows [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/UserManual/ScopingRules) so you can apply it either to single sampler or to a group of samplers.